# Pandas dataframe with less number of columns to SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert some data into a table in sql-server using sqlalchemy and the function `df.to_sql`.

The problem is that the dataframe doesn't have the same number of columns (it has less columns than the sql server table) as the table and for the columns that the dataframe doesn't have, it inserts NULL values. Is there any way to replace the nulls with blank spaces.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://"+creds.un+":"+creds.pw+"@"+creds.svr+"/"+creds.db+"?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server")

final_df.to_sql("table", con = engine, if_exists = "append", index = False)
```

final_df is missing about 2 columns that are not nullable.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the database column to default to '' instead of null for omitted values, or specify the column in your dataframe and perhaps do a final_df.fillna('', inplace=True)

Comment: I was looking for something that wouldn't require such a modification. Appreciate your repsonse.

Comment: Hey! Did you find a solution to this?